# How to add number of days to a custom Date captured from Correlation function?

Tags: performance, date, loadrunner

I am looking for logic which can add couple of days to a custom date(not current date)

Below is Correlation function:

```
 web_reg_save_param("Recommended_Date",
            "LB=\"start\":\"",
            "RB/DIG=T##:##:##\",",
            "Ord=1",
            "Search=Body",
            LAST);
```

I want to add +21 days to Recommended_Date parameter. I tried doing below thing but no luck

```
lr_save_datetime("%Y-%M-%D", lr_eval_string("{Recommended_Date}") + (ONE_DAY*21), "New_Date");
```

Can anyone please assist me.

Comment: Why do you not use DevWeb....

Comment: I am not sure how DevWeb works (and also dont have vuser Licence), do we have a provision to solve this issue there? @Buzzy

Comment: Search DevWeb on YouTube and you will get tutorial videos from installation to your first load test. It is MUCH simpler to write scripts there because it uses JavaScript. It is part of LoadRunner and you can get the free version with 50 vusers by downloading LoadRunner Developer package from the marketplace.

Comment: https://marketplace.microfocus.com/appdelivery/content/LoadRunner-Developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of our engineers prepared this example for you:

```
int diff_days(char * dateString, char * dateFormat) {
    
int year, month, day; 
struct tm info;
double delta;
double days=0;

time_t today;

    time(&today);
    
    sscanf(dateString, dateFormat, &year, &month, &day);
    
    info.tm_year = year - 1900;
    info.tm_mon = month - 1;
    info.tm_mday = day;
//      info.tm_hour = 0;
//      info.tm_min = 0;
//      info.tm_sec = 0;
    info.tm_isdst = -1;

    mktime(&info);
    delta = difftime(mktime(&info),today);

    if (delta >= 0)  {
        days = difftime(mktime(&info),today)/ 86400.0 +1;
    } else {
        days = difftime(mktime(&info),today)/ 86400.0;
    }

    return (int)days;   
}

Action()
{
    
    int plus;
    
    lr_save_string("2020-09-01","D2");

    plus = diff_days(lr_eval_string("{D2}"),"%d-%d-%d");
    
    lr_save_datetime("%Y-%m-%d", DATE_NOW + ONE_DAY*(21+plus), "New_Date");
    

    lr_save_string("2020/04/05","D2");

    plus = diff_days(lr_eval_string("{D2}"),"%d/%d/%d");
    
    lr_save_datetime("%Y/%m/%d", DATE_NOW + ONE_DAY*(21+plus), "New_Date");    
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```